# URL Rewrite web.config

Tags: url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i need little help with url rewrite. My php site is running on windows server. I am trying to rewrite urls so both categories and articles looks like this:

hxxp://domain.com/category-name
hxxp://domain.com/article-title

This is what i have in web.config. It's working fine for categories but not for articles, what am i doing wrong?

```
<rule name="category">
    <match url="^([_0-9a-z-]+)" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="category.php?slug={R:1}" />
</rule>
<rule name="article">
    <match url="^([_0-9a-z-]+)" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="article.php?slug={R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the rules are triggered in the order they are displayed. So you need something to avoid triggering the first rule when you want to rewrite the article.

For example, following the convention you have, it could be:

```
<rule name="category">
    <match url="^category-([_0-9a-z-]+)" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="category.php?slug={R:1}" />
</rule>
<rule name="article">
    <match url="^article-([_0-9a-z-]+)" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="article.php?slug={R:1}" />
</rule>
```

The first rule will only be triggered if the path starts with `category-` and the second one only if it starts with `article-`.

Note that using `{R:1}` as a back reference you will only have what's after `category-` or `article-` so if you want to keep the same behavior as before, you can use `{R:0}` instead.